# HTML5 audio tag sends partial GET request to cloudfront url

Tags: html, html5-audio, amazon-cloudfront

I am having this weird issue where if I use any url with

```
    <audio src="myurl" />
```

it works fine but if I use my cloudfront url it sends GET request fine but I get HTTP 206 Response.

If I try to download the file from my cloudfront url directly from address bar of the URL then it downloads fine. Also if I make a request to that url via chrome Rest API client then also I get 200 OK response. Only with this audio tag for this url for some reason I keep seeing 206 response in the network console of the chrome.

Any idea what might be going wrong?